# Moq: Mocking a class with multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, moq, legacy-code

I'm working getting some tests in on legacy code (here meaning "code without unit tests"). Sometimes good practices are followed, but often times not. I haven't been able to figure out what needs to be done in this case though.

I need to be able to test the method I want in a concrete class, but have been unable to because in the constructor of the class I am testing, it not only has parameters of interfaces which I can mock, but it also inherits from another base class which has its own dependencies.

The method I want to test is FilterController.SomeMethod(whatever_params). FilterController inherits from BaseController. And I've added in a simple interface IFilterController to make it so FilterController inherits from both BaseController and IFilterController. The only method I have in the interface is the method I want to test ("SomeMethod").

Right now the constructor of the FilterController is where I am running into the issues when it jumps into the BaseController.

```
public interface IFilterController { ActionResult SomeMethod(string s, bool b) }

public class FilterController : BaseController, IFilterController {
    public FilterController(IFoo1 foo1, IFoo2 foo2, IFoo3 foo3, IFoo4 foo4)
        : base(typeof(FilterController), foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4) {}
    public ActionResult SomeMethod(string s, bool b) { // implementation }


// and the BaseController...
public BaseController(Type type, IFoo1 foo1, IFoo2 foo2, IFoo3 foo3, IFoo4 foo4)
    {
        // call that blows up due to not knowing how to mock the call inside here
        _somePrivateProperty = _someOtherInterface.someCallThatIsntMocked(some_params)
       // other stuff
    }
```

The code I currently have for trying to setup the unit test (MSTest with FluentAssertions and Moq):

```
    private FilterController filterController;
    private Mock<IFilterController> filterControllerMock;
    private Mock<IFoo1> foo1mock;
    private Mock<IFoo2> foo2mock;
    private Mock<IFoo3> foo3mock;
    private Mock<IFoo4> foo4mock;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context) {}

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        filterControllerMock = new Mock<IFilterController>();
        foo1mock = new Mock<IFoo1>();
        foo2mock = new Mock<IFoo2>();
        foo3mock = new Mock<IFoo3>();
        foo4mock = new Mock<IFoo4>();

        // here is where the test bombs out with exceptions due to the base class making calls to stuff not mocked
        filterController = new FilterController(foo1mock.Object, foo2mock.Object, foo3mock.Object, foo4mock.Object);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup(){}

    [ExpectedException(typeof(CustomException))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeMethod_ForcedErrorScenario_CatchesCustomException()
    {
        // Arrange
        filterControllerMock
            .Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns(new CustomException());

        // Act
        var result = filterController.SomeMethod("Foobar", false);        
    }
```

In this case there is a Try Catch block that I am making sure is handled properly when it gets to the catch block to confirm a bug was fixed. I don't care how the exception is thrown for the purpose of the test, just that it is caught and does what I expect it to after. However, like I said, I cannot get past trying to mock the FilterController constructor itself to make the call to its concrete method due to the BaseController it inherits from.

--
**EDIT**: Resolved the issue. In BaseController, the _someOtherInterface was instantiated based on one of the interfaces passed in the constructor. In my MSTest Initialize method I just had to make it so that interface would not be a null reference and then override the method it called to with Setup(x=>x.otherMethod()).Returns(_someOtherInterface.Object).

Comment: how does the real application instantiate `_someOtherInterface`?  It's not injected.  It seems like you'll need to refactor that to get it working.

Comment: I just figured out that part. It takes one of the interfaces passed in the constructor to call out and instantiate the other interface. I just had to add a call in the Initialize method to setup that mocked interface to override the method it calls. I'll update OP but the original issue is resolved. Actually, the new issue is so far off from the original, I would rather create a new thread entirely for it. I'll crack away at it for a while to see if I can figure it out on my own first.

Comment: glad to hear you're making progress

Comment: Write the solution up as an answer to the question and give it a check mark so it may help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Found out my issue... in BaseController

```
// I didn't realize the _someOtherInterface was instantiated based off an interface passed in
_someOtherInterface = _IFoo1.AMethodNotMocked();
// many lines later...
_somePrivateProperty = _someOtherInterface.SomeMockedMethod()
```

To resolve the issue I had to then make it so in the [TestInitialize] Initialize method before it tried to create the filterController = new FilterController(interfacemock.Object) stuff, I had to override _IFoo1.AMethodNotMocked. Like so:

```
IFoo1.Setup(s => AMethodNotMocked()).Returns(new Foobar())
```

This made it so when the test called into FilterController, the IFoo1 interface was populated so a null reference error wasn't thrown.